# What happens if a response takes longer than the delay set in Postman Runner

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm running tests with a delay set to 2 seconds on the Test Runner on Postman.

I'm just wondering if a response took longer than this, let says 5 seconds, does the next request get sent straight away after this response (because it's gone past the 2 seconds) ?

Answer (score 2):

The `delay` is between each request. Once the response is received, then the delay starts.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/intro-to-collection-runs/#starting-a-collection-run

This isn't the same as the `request timeout` setting.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/settings/#request